# Cannot partition physical hard disk in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning

My PC is running Ubuntu 20.04. I created a raw vmdk so that I can use my physical hard disk inside the VM. On the VM I run `gparted` and format one of the partitions. However, when I open `gparted` on my host machine, it says that the partition is unformatted. I still can't figure out why this is happening after 2 days.

Notice that the selected unformatted partition is labeled as ntfs on the gparted running virtually.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Been a while, so ill also post this on askubuntu." – Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Comment: ill edit my question, and the site wont even let me cross-post so that fixes itself. also, thanks for not instantly disliking and deleting my question like they would on stack overflow cuz it happens to me alot, even though its probably my fault.

Comment: Did you reboot the system after changing the partition in the VM?  I suspect that there is some caching going on somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the host server?  It sounds like there is some caching going on.  If not, can you confirm if /dev/sdb on the server is mapped to /dev/sda on the VM (ie not mapping /dev/sdb**4** to /dev/sda)

Comment: I can confirm that the mapping is correct. I refreshed gparted multiple times before posting this question so I don't think either of those are the problem, however i found another way to create the vmdk file that i will try next time i get the chance (which isn't right now because im on another device). thanks for the help though :)

Comment: `I created a raw vmdk so that I can use my physical hard disk inside the VM` a vmdk is a virtual disk, not a physical disk